# PHP ciclos y color

Tags: php, bucles, color

Tengo que generar este texto con ciclos y también ir bajando la intensidad del color rgb con incrementos en 4 en 4 con PHP, lo tengo que imprimir con un echo en una página web

[image: SECUENCIA]

Comment: Hola, ¿cual es el código que has intentado?

Comment: En que contexto estas hablando? porque no es lo mismo en pagina web, que en consola, o en otro dispositivo de salida...

Comment: si el resultado me lo piden en una pagina web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías explicar un poco mejor qué quieres hacer y compartir el código que has intentado.

En cualquier caso, si lo único que necesitas es generar mediante PHP un código como el de la imagen que adjuntas, sería algo así:

```
<?php

// Número de veces que vas a mostrar la palabra
$repeticiones = 6;

// Calcula la diferencia de opacidad entre cada una de las repeticiones
$reduccion = number_format(1 / $repeticiones, 6);

for ($i = 0; $i < $repeticiones; $i++)
{
    // Calcula la opacidad en base a la repetición en la que se está y la diferencia de opacidad entre cada una de ellas
    $opacidad = 1 - $reduccion * $i;

    // Imprime una capa con dos estilos: uno para convertir a mayúsculas y otro para definir la opacidad
    echo '<div style="text-transform: uppercase; opacity: ' . $opacidad . '">Ayuda</div>';
}

?>
```

Si por lo que sea, no supieses el número de repeticiones de la palabra o tuvieses varias palabras distintas, también podrías hacerlo guardando dichas palabras en un array:

```
<?php

// Array con las palabras
$palabras = array('Nada de ayuda', 'Algo de ayuda', 'Mucha ayuda');

// Calcula el número de repeticiones leyendo cuántos elementos tiene el array
$repeticiones = count($palabras);

// Calcula la diferencia de opacidad entre cada una de las repeticiones
$reduccion = number_format(1 / $repeticiones, 6);

for ($i = 0; $i < $repeticiones; $i++)
{
    // Calcula la opacidad en base a la repetición en la que se está y la diferencia de opacidad entre cada una de ellas
    $opacidad = 1 - $reduccion * $i;

    // Imprime una capa incluyendo las palabras del array con dos estilos: uno para convertir a mayúsculas y otro para definir la opacidad
    echo '<div style="text-transform: uppercase; opacity: ' . $opacidad . '">' . $palabras[$i] . '</div>';
}

?>
```

Si tienes alguna duda respecto al funcionamiento de la propiedad CSS **opacity**, puedes consultar más información [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp).

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda :)